# Mp3 resource encoded as text in Intellij IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, encoding, resources, mp3

everyone.

- I have mp3 file in Intellij IDEA project under resources dir - '*src\main\resources\com\company\app\sound\type.mp3*'
- When I rebuild project, the file appears in target - 'classes\com\company\app\sound\type.mp3'
- But it has different size and wrong binary data.

**I've found out that IDEA is to blame.**

- it copies mp3 resource as text
- and unexpectedly encodes it from ASCII (why??) to UTF-8 (default charset in project)
- Maven build does the same.

**I've tried**

- setting encoding for the mp3 file ASCII (though it's nonsence) - gives target file of correct size, but not playable
- adding *.mp3 to Compiler -> Resource patterns - no effect

**I'm looking for**

- an IDEA setting that will recognize mp3 file as binary, not text.
- or a better way to store binarry resources (though my images are ok)

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The bug was in my pom.xml
Resource filtering was set to true